# 16 A appliance into 30 A outlet

Tags: power-supply

I am hoping someone with electrical system knowledge can help clear something up for me. I am considering purchasing an appliance the requires a 230V, 16A outlet. I asked an electrician about wiring on the same Male plug as my dryer which is 220V 30A so I could simply use the same outlet and he said I couldn't do so because I would need a specific 220V 15 amp outlet. But from looking online and reading about amps, it seems that as long as I'm not EXCEEDING the amps, then it shouldn't matter. I am wondering if using this outlet will cause any risk of fire or electrocution because the amperage is higher? Also if it could damage the appliance since it's quite expensive. Any input is really appreciated because I know nothing about this type of thing.

Thank you

EDIT: I am in Canada. The product is Speidel product#22200(pome fruit grinder). Note that in the manual it says its 50 Hz but they now have a version for North America that is 60. I couldn't upload a picture of my outlet but will try again.

Comment: This should maybe be migrated to DIY forum? Anyway, the underlying intention in the electric code is to make sure that wires are protected by breakers such that the breaker will trip before the wire gets so hot it can start a fire, no matter what fault may occur. The cord on your 16A appliance is probably too small (in diameter) to carry 30A. If you put a 20A fuse in the appliance cord, then it would probably be OK. Or if you know it has a 20A fuse inside of it, then it would also probably be OK. As a side note, you can easily wire the male plug yourself but all liability is then on you.

Comment: I don't know what country you are in but here is an adaptor designed to allow you to plug a 20 Amp appliance into a 30A outlet (these are US type 240V outlets). If it was all that dangerous, I imagine such adaptors would be banned. You might ask your electrician about this. https://www.pduwhips.com/products/2036-l6-30p-to-6-20r-plug-adapter.aspx

Comment: @mkeith: *"The cord on your 16A appliance is probably too small (in diameter) to carry 30A."* That logic doesn't make any sense. Why am I allowed to plug a 100 W table lamp with an AWG18 line cord into a wall outlet that's fused at 15 A? The breakers in the house are sized to protect the wiring *in the walls*, not anything you might plug into the outlets!

Comment: @DaveTweed consider failure modes, the conductors need to be rated to carry whatever the breaker might supply.

Comment: @DaveTweed, these arguments have been raised again and again in different forums. I am not strongly attached to that argument and I am not going to defend it. Just trying to think of any reason that the installation would not be OK. That is all I could come up with. Trying to give the electrician the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: Branch circuit breakers are sized to protect the wiring in the wall. They are not sized to protect cord and plug connected loads. However I believe they are expected to disconnect faulted equipment from the circuit without such equipment starting a fire. I believe that UL listed equipment is listed for connection to branch circuits conforming to the requirements for circuits with receptacles matching the plug with which they are sold. NEC specifies specific receptacles as permitted for 15, 20, 30, 40 & 50 amp circuits. As usual, the applicable code is unknown. If my guess is wrong, never mind.

Comment: I'm not all all familiar with the Canadian electrical code, but from a pure electric point of view, placing a 16 A fuse downstream from your existing 30 A one will satisfy what the machine was type tested for. How you legally and practically implement it you need to ask you electrician about.

Comment: The wiring can stay, but the breaker would have to be down-sized to 20A (80% of full-load current).  The outlet could stay, but you'd either have to change the receptacle or the plug from the fruit grinder.  A problem may be in finding 20A receptacle to handle 30A wiring.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the outlet is capable of delivering 30A without tripping. The wiring in your 16A device may not be equipped to handle a 30A surge, and could therefore sustain damage because the electrical service can deliver more amperage in a failure mode. Or worse, if your power cable isn't up to the task of managing the heat of a sustained surge, it could cause a fire hazard.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED AGAIN

That is a serious machine. It is not clear from the available information what type of motor it is, but it is possibly a 3 HP motor. It may work OK on a 20A breaker, but it is perfectly reasonable to put it on a 30A breaker. Your existing outlet will work fine.

You mention that your dryer outlet has 4 prongs (please let me know if that is wrong). That means it is a NEMA 14-30 type receptacle. So all you need to do is go to the hardware store, tell them you need a NEMA 14-30 plug (or just find it on the shelf yourself).

On your cord coming out of the grinder, one of the three wires will be Ground (probably green insulation or green with yellow stripe). Make sure you connect ground correctly to the ground prong on the plug. The other two wires will probably be some European colors. Maybe blue and brown. These are both "hot"and should connect to the two hot prongs on the plug. Order doesn't matter. The neutral prong on the plug will not be connected to any wire since you don't need neutral, and the grinder doesn't have a neutral wire.

This will work fine as long as you do it like I said. This is what I would do myself. It is just the tinyest bit "bush league" but it is better than replacing the receptacle for your dryer. If you really want, you can replace the dryer receptacle with a NEMA 6-30 receptacle and put a NEMA 6-30 plug on your grinder. But then you won't be able to plug in your dryer anymore.

[image: NEMA connectors]

Image credit: Orion Lawlor

[license: CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)

Comment: I think the machine is 16 A and the socket is 30.

Comment: @OskarSkog I found the manual for the machine. It is a bit confusing because it is primarily a Euro product. But there is a North American version. The manual says install no less than 16A fuse or breaker. So it needs to be at least 20A breaker (since there is no such thing as a 16A breaker). The manual does not give a maximum, and it apparently does not come with a plug attached. So I think it is totally reasonable to install a 30A plug to match the 30A socket. Sorry if that didn't come across in my answer.

Comment: 16A is a standard breaker size in Europe.

Comment: @SimonB, I didn't know that. But OP is in Canada.

Comment: To mkeith,  you commented about adding a 30 A plug and using that. This makes sense to me, but after speaking to both the local distributor of the apple mill, and also someone at an electrical supply store I am totally confused as to if I can use my outlet. The outlet has 4 slots for 4 prongs. As I understand it this is for 2 live wires, a ground, and a neutral. The distributor told me that we "dont have neutral lines in canada" and that there is no way that my dryer has a  4 prong outlet because that would be 3 phase(commercial connection".

Comment: You comments that the mill only uses 3 wires and this is correct and that I would simply not use the neutral. But when i spoke with the guy at the electrical store, he says i will have to put in a totally new outlet that only has the 2 live and 1 ground. It seems that no one is giving the full picture. I dont know how the distributor is correct in saying we dont have neutral lines in canada because the other person said that was wrong. This is expensive equipment and I wish I could just get a clear answer about the outlet. I appreciate everyone's information and now know that 30A is ok.

Comment: The distributor said there will be no issue hooking it up to a dryer outlet, the problem is is if I purchase it and then cannot connect it, I am out well over 1000$. Which is too big a loss to take a chance. Long story short, any input as to if I can still use a 4 prong outlet(2 live, 1 ground, 1 neutral) with only 3 wires (2 live, 1 ground) is very welcome since I'm thinking someone I have spoken to is incorrect.

Comment: Canada definitely has neutral lines. Distributor is wrong. Modern electric code requires 4-prong outlets for dryers. The reason I wanted you to post a picture of the dryer outlet was so I could tell if it is a modern 4-prong one or an older 3-prong style. The 4-prong outlet is NEMA 14-30. (google that). You can ABSOLUTELY attach a NEMA 14-30 plug to the wire for the grinder. Inside the plug, you just don't connect anything to the neutral prong. Connect the Ground wire to the Ground prong. The other two wires can be attached to the two hot prongs (doesn't matter which one is which).

Answer (score 0):

Drawing 15Amps of current from 30Amps outlet is totally safe. Practically you cant run a 15A appliance from a 16A outlet. The outlet and mains wire will heat up over time due to heavy current flow. Its best to provide some headroom.

Answer (score 0):

The Canadian code is similar to NEC, but not identical. I am not familiar with CSA code, but I have some familiarity with NEC. You should first verify that the appliance has a CSA label. If the appliance does not have internal motor overload protection, code probably specifies a maximum branch circuit breaker rating. The circuit can probably be legitimately converted to a 20 A circuit by replacing the circuit breaker and receptacle. You need to have an electrician look at the manual for North America and markings on the product and preferably also the actual product. Motorized products need three types of protection, short circuit protection, overload protection and ground fault protection. The circuit breaker for the branch circuit can provide all three protections under the circumstances spelled out by the electrical code. One of those conditions may be that the CSA listing was obtained with that provision. If that is the case, it should be spelled out in the manual and may require some kind of marking on the product. Note also that the lack of a cord may mean that the product is intended to be direct connected. If that is the case, you may be required to have it installed by a licensed electrician.

If the electrician that you spoke to said that you need a 15 amp outlet he is mistaken or did not have all of the required information. To get this right, you probably need to have an electrician look at everything, not just give an opinion based on your description.

Comment: Ok well it seems that the general consensus is that it is safe. I realized after reading your comments/looking further online that it is logical that it should be safe. Considering that most appliances I'm using on a daily basis use far less amperage than the outlet can supply(phone charger, beard trimmer, food processor etc.) There should be no reason this will be an issue. I guess worse case scenario is I could get an adapter to change the current going into the appliance to 20A. But as some of you have said, there is no need to do so. Thank you all for the info. It's much appreciated

Comment: I am now seeing online that the cord provided with the mill may only be thick enough to handle 20A for the north American version. Is there a device I could use to make it so the 30A coming from the outlet is changed to 20A? I know there are adapters for generators that say "30A to 20A" but does that mean the cord(if plugged into an adapter of this sort) will now only have to handle 20A?I realize that this may be a stupid question, but I really have no idea about this type of information.

Comment: It is the load that determines the actual current drawn from the source. The only limit is the circuit breaker that shuts the power off completely if the load draws too much current. That is why it needs to be changed to a 20A breaker if you change to a 20A receptacle.